# Auto sys file watcher job

Tags: job-scheduling, autosys

Task: Is to create file watcher job in autosys that would watch out for a particular file.

The requirement is that the file comes at 9:00am everyday and the file watcher job starts running by 8.50am. If the file is received by 10:00 am then job should terminate successfully else an alert email(thru SSIS package, another autosys job) should be triggered.

I'm using Autosys(windows). 
I'm not sure how to tell file watcher job to Start looking for file around 8:50am and end looking for file at 10:00 am and if the file is not received by 10 am then trigger another auto sys job. How to set this up.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Cindy!!

Answer (score 3):

for the first job:
start_times: "08:50"
term_run_time: 70

for the second job:
condition: failure(first_job)